# Post message on facebook wall from iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I want to post some message on Facebook wall.

I am able to log in and connect with Facebook from iPhone. But I have hard luck to finding out the solution.

Can you please tell me how I can achieve this functionality?

Comment: I think you'll need to add a little more information if you want your question answered.  For example, we can't really tell if you are doing this in code, or via an App. If via code, what have you used so far that was successful, and what has failed?  If via an app then I'm not sure this is the place to ask such questions (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Sorry if i told in wrong fashion. I mean i am integrating facebook with my iPhone application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have a valid FBSession Object:

```
    FBStreamDialog* dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    dialog.delegate = self; dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Example prompt"; 
    dialog.attachment = @"{\"name\":\"Facebook Connect for iPhone\"," "\"href
    \":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone\"," "\"caption\":\"Caption
    \",\"description\":\"Description\"," "\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\"," "\"src 
    \":\"http://img40.yfrog.com/img40/5914/iphoneconnectbtn.jpg\"," "\"href
    \":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone/\"}]," "\"properties     \":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"Facebook home page\",\"href\":\"http://www.facebook.com\"}}}"; // replace this with a friend's UID // dialog.targetId = @"999999"; 
    [dialog show];
```

[Source: Facebook Connect Reference](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_for_iPhone#Publishing_Feed_Stories_to_the_Stream)

Comment: I also figure out the second way. You can use stream.publish method to post message silently on facebook wall.

The method mentioned by Henrik also works fine. 
once again thanks for help.