# post message to users wall

Tags: iphone

i am creating a iphone application using Facebook SDK.I want to post message to  friends wall.can u help me to implement this..

Comment: Google says:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054915/post-message-on-facebook-wall-from-iphone

Comment: Use these links http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/ http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app

Comment: Maybe you should read this, too: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@sai** You can post a message to your friends wall by using the Facebook SDK. You just need to do following task:

1. First find your friend's FacebookID (I assume you have it)
2. Then do this:

```
-(void)sendMessageToFriendWall{

   NSString* friendID=@"here Please Add Friends FacebookID";

   NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:    
                                   friendID, @"to",messageToBePost,@"message",nil];

   [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@

   /feed",friendID] andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST"  andDelegate:self];

}
```

If you don't have your friends's Id, you can find him and his ID using the below method call:

```
-(void)getFriendsandTheirId{

  [delegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self]; 

}
```

This will return a json of friends and their facebook IDs. After getting your friend's ID, you can Post on his Wall.

Please don't Forget to Adopt `FBRequestDelegate` in your Controller Class.