# iPhone/iOS: How to make Facebook-Wallpost with custom Dialog

Tags: iphone, facebook

I've seen many examples on how to make a facebook-Wallpost using the facebook-SDK for iphone (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054915/post-message-on-facebook-wall-from-iphone) for example). They all go something like this:

```
[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

However I dont want the Facebook-Dialog to appear, but instead use my own dialog. Anyone ran into the same issue before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

This line will pop-up the FB-Dialog in order to avoid this first pop-up your custom dialog and then call the following action on done button (Or whatever you want to call it)

-(void) myCustomDialogPostButtonAction:(NSString *)msg
{

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                               msg, @"message", 
                               nil];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                     andParams:params  
                 andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
                   andDelegate:self];
```

}

I hope this helps.